# How to display a BLOB image stored in my SQLite database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, blob, tkinter-entry

I have a CRUD form with entries and 4 button for **deleting, updating, creating, getting** values from my database, I want to implement another button to open an imagen which is binded to my **id entry** also able to works with my **deleting, updating, creating, getting** buttons, I've been trying to use BLOB and I'm able to save an image in my database as BLOB. Actually I understand that I need to create **textvariables** for my entries like 'idvar = StringVar() , namevar = Stringvar()..., etc', So I'm not sure how to do it for an image label in order to work with my CRUD buttons **deleting, updating, creating, getting**

**This is my code I got so far and it's working well saving images into my photos columns:**

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

top = Tk()
top.configure(width='444', heigh='400')

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def enterdata():
    id = 'hello'
    photo = convert_pic()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO test (id, photo) VALUES (?, ?)', (id, photo)) #Here my id has integer value and my photo has BLOB value in my database 
    conn.commit()

def convert_pic():
    filename = 'images/image6.jpg'
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        photo = file.read()
    return photo


btn = Button(top, text='save photo', command=enterdata)
btn.place(x='100', y='111')


mainloop()
```

Comment: Note: `command=enterdata()` should be `command=enterdata`.

Comment: Is the images saved correctly in the database?

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes, the image `'images/image6.jpg'` is saved correctly in my database when I push the button `btn = Button(top, text='save photo', command=enterdata`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have the BLOB you can use `io.BytesIO`. I will create an example to demonstrate, like:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from io import BytesIO

def show(data):
    img_byte = BytesIO(data)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img_byte))
    Label(root,image=img).pack()
    root.image = img # Keep a reference
```

So now you can query the database and fetch the value:

```
def fetch():
    c = con.cursor()
    id = 1 # Any id
    c.execute('SELECT photo FROM test where id=?',(id,))
    data = c.fetchall()[0][0] # Get the blob data
    show(data) # Call the function with the passes data
```

This will show the image in a label in the root window for the entered id.

Comment: @CooCloud it shows this error `IndexError: tuple index out of range` , I took [0][1] because my photo is in the second column

Comment: @Paul Did you try `[0][0]`, because we are just selecting one column.

Comment: I tried `[0][0]` but once push button designed to call that function it seems the the photo charged and it expands the window but I can't see the photo itself

Comment: @Paul Sorry, my bad, add `root.image = img` to the end of `show()`.

Comment: Awesome, it's working fine, though I'm little confused about my CRUD form, could you give me some advices how to implement it with photos?, should I post another question or just write it here directly?

Comment: @Paul Better to ask a new questions, try to keep it non opinionated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229622/discussion-between-paul-and-cool-cloud).